# Excel: Challenging formula sought for counting records

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am looking for some help with a formula. On my 'data' sheet, I have data in the format below:

```
   A         B            C            D            E          F        G           H           I          J
1 UID   RecordType      HCode     AdmittedDate   Forename   Surname    DOB          Sex      STDate      RDate
2 87962 STAsses         STIV1     01/01/2012     Mark       Jones      13/07/1978   Male     09/12/2012 
3 89658 Transfer        GLSI2     01/01/2012     Alison     Aitken     20/12/1956   Female               08/07/2013 
4 84563 Discharge       JHOP1     01/01/2012     David      Beckham    09/08/1987   Male                 08/07/2013
5 89654 STAsses         STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth    27/09/1976   Male     08/07/2012 
6 89867 Transfer        KIND1     01/01/2012     George     Deas       08/05/1989   Male                 08/07/2013
7 87962 Transfer        STIV1     01/01/2012     Mark       Jones      13/07/1978   Male                 04/03/2013 
8 89654 Transfer        STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth    27/09/1976   Male                 12/08/2012
```

On my 'report' sheet, I have the following table set up:

```
      B             C             D          E         F
4 HospCode     RecordType      Jul-12     Aug-12    Sep-12
5 STGE1        Assessments
6              Transfers
7              Discharges
8
```

I would like to do 2 things.

1. In D5, E5, F5, a formula is needed to return the number of 'STAssess' records for HCode 'STGE1' from the data sheet, which were completed in the month shown in D4 of the 'report' sheet (Jul-12). The dates for these records are in column I of the data sheet - 'STDate'.

I've tried using SUMPRODUCT which works to an extent, but I'm having difficulty bringing back records only completed in July. I need the formula to be dynamic in that it only brings back results for the month entered in D4 (so a date range built into the formula isn't doing the job).

1. In D5, E5, F5, I need to bring back the number of records from the 'data' sheet, which have 'Transfer' in column B (RecordType), 'STGE1' in column C (HCode) and a date in column J (RDate) which falls in the month specified on D4 of the 'report' sheet (Jul-12).

Anyone got any ideas? The data sheet is actually going to be an external .csv file which can't be manipulated. I don't mind using other hidden sheets to do any sorting that needs to be done, provided that this can be setup so that when the data is brought in, no extra work has to be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both of your questions you can use `COUNTIFS`. It is easier to understand (for me) and compatible with Excel 2007 and newer.

First question:

```
=COUNTIFS(DATA!B:B,"STAsses",DATA!C:C,$B5,DATA!I:I,">="&D$4,DATA!I:I,"<"&DATE(YEAR(D4),MONTH(D4)+1,1))
```

Second question:

```
=COUNTIFS(DATA!B:B,"Transfer",DATA!C:C,$B5,DATA!J:J,">="&D$4,DATA!J:J,"<"&DATE(YEAR(D4),MONTH(D4)+1,1))
```

And these formulas can be dragged across your needed range.

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much for your help with this. The first one definitely works. Not sure on the second one just yet, but it looks promising. Tried to vote up, but it won't let me just yet (not enough reputation!).

Can you give me a brief explanation of how the second formula works to ensure it's only counting 'Transfer' records which also have a corresponding 'STAssess' record. The STAssess record can have been done at any time.

Comment: thanks. You can mark as the answer if it suits your needs. That will let others know that this worked for you in case they have similar needs. As for `Transfer` that have a corresponding `STAssess` record, that's a tricky one (and not part of you original question). I'd have to think about it some, but it seems like you would need to have some helper columns to make that happen. What I would do, to keep this question clean, is to use this new requirement and create new question.

Comment: Thanks again. You're absolutely right. I meant to add that as a third condition to my 2nd question, but having re-read it there, I clearly didn't. Will ask separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example formula that you could use for the D5 cell, does that point you in the right direction?:

```
{=SUM(IF($B$2:$B$8=$B14,IF($C$2:$C$8=$A14,IF($D$2:$D$8=C$13,1,0),0),0))}
```

This is an array function so you must enter it without the {} at each end and use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter the formula.

Comment: Thanks for this starting point. I was already at a similar stage, but there are some problems with it. e.g., the last part of the SUM function you provided - what is the C13 reference for?

Comment: Here is the same formula with correct references added:

=SUM(IF(Data!B2:B8="STAssess",IF(Data!C2:C8=Report!B5,IF(Data!I2:I8=D4,1,0),0),0))

I suspect it's the last part for the date range that's causing the result to be 0 (it should be 1). On the data sheet, column I contains a list of dates in format DD/MM/YYYY. The formula should count dates in this column in the month typed in D4 of the report sheet (Jul-12).

Answer (score 0):

If your summary table looks like

```
HospCode    RecordType  12-Jul  12-Aug  12-Sep
STGE1       STAsses     1       0       0
STGE1       Transfer    0       1       0
STGE1       Discharges  0       0       0
```

And your data is in a table called Table1, then in D5

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[HCode]=$B5)*(Table1[RecordType]=$C5)*(MONTH(Table1[STDate])=MONTH(D$4)))
```

I'm not sure what you mean by 'bring back', but assume you mean that you want to show it when RecordType = column C *and* when the RecordType = "Transfer" and the RDate is in the right month.  Then

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Table1[HCode]=$B5)*(Table1[RecordType]=$C5)*(MONTH(Table1[STDate])=MONTH(D$4)))+SUMPRODUCT((Table1[HCode]=$B5)*(Table1[RecordType]="Transfer")*(MONTH(Table1[RDate])=MONTH(D$4)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The data is not in a table. It's in a sheet called 'data' and is completely unformatted. It's copied from a .csv file, but I want to be able to reference the .csv file directly once the formulas are sorted.

By 'bring back', I simply meant 'count'. What I don't want is just to count all the 'transfer' records for the HCode in B5, and in month shown in D4. 

I want it to only count the 'transfer' records for the HospCode shown in Report!B5, with a date in Data!J:J = to that in Report!D4 and only if there has previously been an 'STAssess' record for the same UID.

Comment: I've modified your second formula to use the appropriate sheet/cell references, but I now get an error in Excel (2013)... "We found a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? When the first character is an equal or minus sign, Excel thinks it's a formula."